# Unable to import data from oracle using Sqoop

Tags: sqoop

Unable to import data from oracle to HDFS using Sqoop. Getting the below error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)

The strange thing is that it comes even if I am specifying a single mapper and as per Sqoop docs should only be generating a single connection to Oracle.

The most weird part is at times the same command gets executed successfully as well.

Any insights on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of sqoop are you using? The reason I am asking is SQOOP-2971 is a known issue and is fixed in versions 1.4.6 and higher. Also makes sure to ping your Oracle DBA and ask him to kill all the existing ORA sessions before you launch sqoop import to database.
Refer to link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2971

Comment: Thank you for your inputs , the sqoop version is 1.4.6-cdh5.12.0, could you please clarify regarding killing of the existing sessions,is it like we have certain restriction because we are specifying multiple mappers to import the data it would be establishing  ORA sessions,please correct me if I am missing something here.

Comment: Sumit You need to check with your DBA on killing the sessions on Exadata side. In a hadoop cluster restarting Sqoop and yarn will clean up all the MR jobs.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was at oracle end as they had restricted sessions for my id, it got resolved once they created a new id with required sessions.